# Convert Form data to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
      <form name="abc" action="#" method="post">
        
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Age : <input type="text" age="name"><br>
        <input type="submit"><br>
        </form>
    
        </body>
</html>
```

Can any one write this HTML code in such a way that when I will submit this form the the form data will be submitted in JSON format .

Comment: What does the server code look like? Why is it expecting JSON?

Answer (score 5):

A pure JavaScript solution would be:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

form.addEventListener('submit',function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var data = {
         "name":this.name.value,
         "age":this.age.value
     };

     console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `name="age"` for `age="name"` at second `input type="text"` , utilizing `.serializeArray()` , `$.post()`

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serializeArray();
  console.log(data);
  // $.post("/path/to/server", data);     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<form name="abc" action="#" method="post">

  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>Age :
  <input type="text" name="age">
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
  <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this function

```
var formDataToObject = function (formElm) {
        var formObj = new FormData(formElm),
            result = {},
            values = formObj.values(),
            keys = formObj.keys(),
            key;


            while (!(key = keys.next()).done) {
                result[key.value] = values.next().value;
            }

        return result;
    };
```

**Two notes here:**

1) No support for multiple select options, it will return the last selected option!!

2) The loop breaks when the next() return object with **done** equals to **true**,
but this object also contains the **key** for the **last element** in the form
which is in most cases the **Submit Button**, so if you don't have one in the form the last element will be excluded, easy to fix.